# regex on hiveql : dangling meta character map reduce

Tags: regex, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

So all, I have been transform my data into hive with talend.

And I run a few of regex. One of those is like this.

```
KRW3TR.899877.GR0054656*DR.798012...2..............GR0054656*EUR*
KRW3TR.899877.GR0054656*DR.798012...2..............GR0054656*EUR*DDT*
KRW3TR.899877.GR0054656*DR.798012...2..............GR0054656*EUR*CCT*
```

What I am trying to do is get the last sequence: `DDT` `CCT`

(from those examples you know that the last sequence sometimes occur)

And I get the error from map reduce :

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)  on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract@a22c4d8 of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with arguments
```

And the other is :

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 9
```

I use this regex to extract this:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(columnrr,'^(?:[^*]*\\*){3}([^*]*)',1) as TYPE
```

My questions are :
Are they related? Is there any business with the occurance of DDT and CCT?
How my regex should be?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `'^(?:[^*]*\\*){3}([^*]*)'`?

Comment: ah ya! thank you! so the answer is my question? should I delete this question?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.
There is reserved character in regex. So the answer is:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(columnrr,'^(?:[^*]*\\\\*){3}([^*]*)',1) as TYPE
```

Related questions : [java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0 +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246231/java-util-regex-patternsyntaxexception-dangling-meta-character-near-index-0)